# Unable to set soap headers camel cxf

Tags: soap, apache-camel, cxf, jbossfuse

I have a camel route which is exposed as soap service,after processsing iam trying to set respone soap headers in java by setting the exchange header org.apache.cxf.headers.Header.list,the header property is set correctly but in response iam not able to see the soap headers.

In the trace logs iam able to see the headers are propogated but in soapui iam not able to see the soap headers.

Am i missing something?

bean declaration cxf endpoint :

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="orderEndpoint" address="http://localhost:8181/order"
        endpointName="s:OrderService" serviceName="s:OrderEndpointService" wsdlURL="wsdl/order.wsdl"
        xmlns:s="http://order.camelinaction"
        loggingFeatureEnabled="true" >
        <cxf:properties>
            <entry key="dataFormat" value="PAYLOAD" />
            <entry key="synchronous" value="true" />
            <!-- <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" /> -->
        </cxf:properties>
    </cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

Java method to set soap headers:

```
public void setSoapHeaders(@Properties Map<String, Object> properties,
            @Headers Map<String, Object> headers) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException {
        List<SoapHeader> soapHeaderList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (properties.get(ESBMetaDataConstant.ESB_METADATA) != null) {
            Metadata metadata = (metadata) properties.get(ESBMetaDataConstant.ESB_METADATA);
            Marshaller m = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            m.marshal(metadata, writer);
            SoapHeader newHeader = new SoapHeader(new QName(ESBMetaDataConstant.ESB_METADATA_NS, "esbns") ,
                    StaxUtils.read(new StringReader(writer.toString())).getDocumentElement());  
            newHeader.setDirection(Direction.DIRECTION_OUT);
            soapHeaderList.add(newHeader);
            headers.put("org.apache.cxf.headers.Header.list", soapHeaderList);
        }

    }
```

Camel Route:

```
 <route id="_route1">

            <from id="_from1" uri="cxf:bean:orderEndpoint"/>
            <bean id="_bean4"
                method="copySoapHeadersToExchangeProperties" ref="metadataHandler"/>
            <bean id="_bean4" method="processData" ref="customProcessor"/>
            <bean
                method="setSoapHeaders" ref="metadataHandler"/>
  </route>
```

Trace logs:

```
16:10:00,231 TRACE [org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer] (qtp2002233485-161) Processing +++ END +++
16:10:00,231 TRACE [org.apache.camel.component.cxf.DefaultCxfBinding] (qtp2002233485-161) Get the response from the out message
16:10:00,231 DEBUG [org.apache.camel.component.cxf.DefaultCxfBinding] (qtp2002233485-161) Propagate to CXF header: accept-encoding value: gzip,deflate
16:10:00,231 DEBUG [org.apache.camel.component.cxf.DefaultCxfBinding] (qtp2002233485-161) Propagate to CXF header: breadcrumbId value: ID-VPE1-D01307-59457-1514473675679-0-4
16:10:00,231 DEBUG [org.apache.camel.component.cxf.DefaultCxfBinding] (qtp2002233485-161) Propagate to CXF header: Host value: localhost:8181
16:10:00,231 TRACE [org.apache.camel.component.cxf.common.header.CxfHeaderFilterStrategy] (qtp2002233485-161) messageHeaderfilter = org.apache.camel.component.cxf.common.header.SoapMessageHeaderFilter@29529744
16:10:00,231 TRACE [org.apache.camel.component.cxf.common.header.SoapMessageHeaderFilter] (qtp2002233485-161) Processing header: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapHeader@4e93cc4d
16:10:00,231 DEBUG [org.apache.camel.component.cxf.DefaultCxfBinding] (qtp2002233485-161) Propagate to CXF header: org.apache.cxf.headers.Header.list value: [org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapHeader@4e93cc4d]
16:10:00,232 TRACE [org.apache.camel.component.cxf.DefaultCxfBinding] (qtp2002233485-161) Propagate SOAP/protocol header: {urn:company:esb:services:schema:message:common:esbmetadata:v01}esb-metadata : [esb-metadata: null]
16:10:00,232 DEBUG [org.apache.camel.component.cxf.DefaultCxfBinding] (qtp2002233485-161) Propagate to CXF header: SOAPAction value: http://order.camelinaction/Order
16:10:00,232 DEBUG [org.apache.camel.component.cxf.DefaultCxfBinding] (qtp2002233485-161) Propagate to CXF header: User-Agent value: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
16:10:00,232 TRACE [org.apache.camel.component.cxf.DefaultCxfBinding] (qtp2002233485-161) Set out response context = {SOAPAction=http://order.camelinaction/Order, org.apache.cxf.message.Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS={accept-encoding=[gzip,deflate], breadcrumbId=[ID-VPE1-D01307-59457-1514473675679-0-4], Host=[localhost:8181], SOAPAction=[http://order.camelinaction/Order], User-Agent=[Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)]}, esb-metadata=com.company.esb.headers.esbMetadata@7037f7dd, CamelCharsetName=UTF-8, CamelMessageHistory=[DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=_route1, node=_bean4], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=_route1, node=_bean4], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=_route1, node=_log1], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=_route1, node=_log2], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=_route1, node=_log3], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=_route1, node=bean1], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=_route1, node=log1]], org.apache.cxf.service.model.BindingOperationInfo=[BindingOperationInfo: {http://order.camelinaction}order], CamelCXFDataFormat=PAYLOAD, jaxwsContext={javax.xml.ws.wsdl.port={http://order.camelinaction}OrderService, javax.xml.ws.wsdl.interface={http://order.camelinaction}OrderEndpoint, javax.xml.ws.wsdl.description=http://localhost:8181/order?wsdl, javax.xml.ws.wsdl.operation={http://order.camelinaction}order, javax.xml.ws.wsdl.service={http://order.camelinaction}OrderEndpointService}, mtom-enabled=false, org.apache.cxf.headers.Header.list=[org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapHeader@4e93cc4d], CamelCreatedTimestamp=Thu Dec 28 16:10:00 CET 2017}
16:10:00,232 TRACE [org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultUnitOfWork] (qtp2002233485-161) UnitOfWork done for ExchangeId: ID-VPE1-D01307-59457-1514473675679-0-3 with Exchange[ID-VPE1-D01307-59457-1514473675679-0-3]
16:10:00,232 TRACE [org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultUnitOfWork] (qtp2002233485-161) Invoking synchronization.onComplete: OnCompletion[CachedOutputStream] with Exchange[ID-VPE1-D01307-59457-1514473675679-0-3]
```

Comment: Where do you call "setSoapHeaders"? Can you post your camel route?

Comment: Updated the camel route details .